# Quickly select lines shortcut in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there any shortcut in eclipse to select lines lets say from line 40 to line 620 without click and dragging the mouse from line 40 to line 620?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the start position and then Shift+Click on the end position.

Comment: thanks but any other shortcut without even navigating to end position?

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are surrounded by parentheses or braces, double-click to the right of the opening bracket or to the left of the closing bracket. This selects all lines between the braces.

Else you can use shift+up/down arrows to select multiple lines.